GPG broken after debian 10 -> 11 upgrade
Just upgraded my Buster server to Debian 11 Bullseye.
However, gpg is now broken.

apt update fails with Unknown error executing apt-key
apt-key --list fails with gpg: symbol lookup error: gpg: undefined symbol: gpgrt_set_confdir, version GPG_ERROR_1.0
any attempt to run gpg fails with the above error.

GPG is version 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 from Debian Bullseye official repository.
Similar errors found online are about building GPG from source, however, I am not doing so, I just installed the binary from Debian repositories.
I tried to reinstall GPG-related packages with no effect.
I plan to upgrade to Debian 12 when this will be solved, obviously I can't do it now since package signatures can't be verified.
Output of ldd /usr/bin/gpg :
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdd2fbb000)
        libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc36ee46000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007fc36ee33000)
        libsqlite3.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0 (0x00007fc36ecf0000)
        libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007fc36ebd0000)
        libreadline.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8 (0x00007fc36eb79000)
        libassuan.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libassuan.so.0 (0x00007fc36eb65000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fc36eb41000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc36e96d000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fc36e829000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc36e807000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc36e801000)
        libtinfo.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.6 (0x00007fc36e7d2000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc36ef7e000)


Thanks for the insight! On another machine with working gpg, every library is from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. On the broken machine, I see 3 of them are instead from /usr/local/lib/. They also exist in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/. So I just symlinked the 3 /usr/local/lib/ libraries to their /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ counterparts. It happens to have fixed the problem.

As you discovered, the error is caused by one of these libraries:
        libreadline.so.8 => /usr/local/lib/libreadline.so.8 (0x00007fc36eb79000)
        libassuan.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libassuan.so.0 (0x00007fc36eb65000)
        libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/local/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007fc36eb41000)

To fix this, you should delete the old libraries in /usr/local/lib. While you’re at it, you might want to check other files in /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib; there might well be more that are older than their equivalents in Debian 11 and 12.
